# Prove that $[A\cup B^\complement\cap C\cup D^\complement]^\complement = A^\complement\cup B^\complement\cap C^\complement\cup D^\complement$ is false.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $$[A\cup B^\complement\cap C\cup D^\complement]^\complement = A^\complement\cup B^\complement\cap C^\complement\cup D^\complement$$

maybe there is a typo right? I think they should be parenthesis somewhere. Otherwise i should make the intersection first right? I'm quite confused.

Comment: Well, it's definitely ambiguous.  I'm under the impression you do intersections and unions left to right unless there are other indications, bu I could be wrong.

Comment: Intersections are generally treated like multiplication and unions are treated like addition, which may help resolve the order of operations here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805630/and-or-order-of-operations

Comment: ok, i think i would make first the intersection then.. thanks guys